# Automapper Unmapped properties:EFState

Tags: c#, automapper

I am using Automapper v4.0.30319 and I am using the base class name AddressBook which has many properties. I have another POCO class named AddressBookPOCO.

I am using this mapping:

```
cfg.CreateMap<BusinessEntities.Entities.AddressBookEntities.AddressBook, BusinessLayerLogic.POCO.AddressBookPOCO>(); 
cfg.CreateMap<BusinessLayerLogic.POCO.AddressBookPOCO, DCF.CARES.BusinessEntities.Entities.AddressBookEntities.AddressBook>().ForMember(dest => dest.EFState, opt => opt.Ignore());
```

After using `EFState` Ignore, calling the automapper object in `EFState` will not change. But when I remove that part of code with `.ForMember(dest => dest.EFState, opt => opt.Ignore());`, it throws the below error:

> Unmapped members were found. Review the types and members below.
>   Add a custom mapping expression, ignore, add a custom resolver, or modify the source/destination type
>
> For no matching constructor, add a no-arg ctor, add optional arguments, or map all of the constructor parameters

---

> AddressBookPOCO -> AddressBook (Destination member list)
>   DCF.Portal.BusinessLayerLogic.POCO.AddressBookPOCO -> DCF.CARES.BusinessEntities.Entities.AddressBookEntities.AddressBook (Destination member list)
>
> Unmapped properties:
>   EFState
>   Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: AutoMapper.AutoMapperConfigurationException:
>   Unmapped members were found. Review the types and members below.
>   Add a custom mapping expression, ignore, add a custom resolver, or modify the source/destination type

For no matching constructor, add a no-arg ctor, add optional arguments, or map all of the constructor parameters.

What can I do?

Comment: Add the property `EFState` to `AddressBookPOCO`.